# AVAudioPlayer 'ticks' when stopped or resumed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, avaudioplayer

I have an .aifc file of about 2 minutes that I'm playing using `AVAudioPlayer`. When I send `stop` I hear a short 'tick'. When I send `play` after that I hear the tick again.

I tried setting `volume` to 0 before sending the `play` and `stop` methods, but that didn't work.

The tick is somewhat comparable to the sound you hear when you disconnect your speakerset from its audio source, but really short (and a lot less loud ofcourse).

Any ideas on how to get rid of the tick?

Comment: Have you tried using another file format? I had that tick and changed to mp3 and wav. No problems since then.

Comment: That didn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by setting the volume to 0.0 without calling `stop`, then calling `stop` a short time after that. No tick at all!

Comment: That's interesting. AVAudioPlayer must be intelligent enough to ramp the volume down gradually rather than instantaneously.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly normal for the audio playback mechanism on any platform to produce ticks like this when stopping and restarting the audio.  To avoid this problem, instead of abruptly stopping playback by calling `stop`, you should first ramp down the volume from 1.0 to 0.0 over a short period of time (a few milliseconds is plenty), and then `stop` or `pause`.  When you resume playback, you would reverse the process by ramping the volume back up from 0.0 to 1.0.

Sorry, I don't know enough iPhonistics to tell you how to do a timer-based operation like this.  I am surprised that the AVAudioPlayer library doesn't do this already, but there are other audio APIs out there that I'm sure do.

**Update:**  On second thought, forget it.  Ramping the volume down with a timer is a horrible idea and won't work.  You'd need a much higher-resolution timer than is possible to avoid a stepping-down effect, which would produce a series of ticks and pops instead of just one.

Use some other API.